# Distribute files across more than one cloud drive

Tags: cloud-storage

I have privacy / data security issues around cloud storage. Is there a way I can scramble my files and distribute them across more than one service so that they cannot be read by any of the providers, regardless of encryption / decryption?

Comment: Typically one would simply use a  Bitlocker encrypted .vhdx and/or VeraCrypt volume.  I would just synchronize this file across my different accounts using the existing tools I use to synchronize files.

Comment: Thanks. Does that result in a complete copy being saved under each account - albeit encrypted - or do the sync tools scramble the file and spread it across the different accounts?

Comment: .vhdx and VeraCrypt files are just files to the operating system.

Comment: OK, sounds like the answer is no then.

Comment: Why do you want to distribute your data *and* encrypt it?  Are you afraid that the cloud service providers can break the encryption? (Whether the  cloud service providers will cooperate with each other to reassemble the fragments of your data seems like an equally, or more, plausible concern.)

Comment: Yes. Neither approach is perfect - encryption is better than distribution if you are just using one, but both together are better than either by itself.